# iphone touches that start from the top above the screen nolonger registering

Tags: iphone, input, touch

I started my app using the original OpenGL ES template that came with the 2.2.1 sdk.  I added the touch callbacks and everything worked fine

but I have now migrated my project to the new OpenGL ES template that came with the 3.1.3 sdk, and everything works fine except now touches that begin above the screen, dragged onto the screen no longer register.  it used to work fine where a touch that started above the screen and then would drag down onto the screen would just register as a normal touch when the finger came onto the screen, but with this new template, even when building it with the 2.2.1 sdk, it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this behaviour on a simulator? No reaction on tapping on top 20 pixels in a fullscreen is considered as a bug: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/43125-iphone-simulator-20pixels-dead-zone.html

Comment: no, it's on the actual device, any device.  it doesn't recognise touches that start off screen, above the screen, and then are dragged down onto the screen.

Comment: Well, I can only say I had a bit similar problem on a device in a simple UIView app. When I put a small info button in the area of hidden status bar on top it used to be less responsive there. Maybe the screen is less sensitive on edges?